# Maintaining and conditioning the seat rail of a Concept2 model D rowing machine

Tags: skiing, rowing-machine

I'm using a Concept2 model D rowing machine. The metal rail along which the seat slides back and forth seems to scratch some plastic particles or small pieces off from the bottom of the seat, and become stained and more coarse than ideal for sliding on. Is it a good idea to wipe it clean and apply some surfboard wax like https://www.sexwax.com/what-is-sex-wax/ to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also own a model D that I've had in service for about 13 years.  During that time, I've definitely experienced what you're talking about.  While it may be tempting to want to lubricate the rail, it is not required.  The residue on the rail you're seeing is normal as indicated from the [Concept2 website](https://www.concept2.com/service/indoor-rowers/model-d/troubleshooting/black-residue-monorail).

> **Black Residue on Monorail**
>
> *Symptom*
>
> There is black residue on the top of the monorail.
>
> *Resolution*
>
> Black flecks on your rail are normal. They are a combination of dirt,
> perspiration, molydisulfide (a lubricant from the plastic rollers) and
> a very small amount of the nylon plastic that the rollers are made of.
> These four components are subjected to the mechanical action of the
> rollers and can dry and harden on the rail. To remove the black
> residue, clean the monorail. Wipe the monorail with a cloth or
> non-abrasive scouring pad after use. You can use soap and water or any
> glass cleaner. Do not use mineral acids, bleach or coarse abrasives.

I find that, on average, I need to wipe the rail on my erg every other session.  In addition, I find that wiping the rollers under the seat with a paper towel while sitting on it and moving up and down the rail tends to remove more residue.